# Можно ли обычные переменные называть как массив?

Tags: php, синтаксис

Привет всем! Можно ли назвать переменную таким образом, к примеру:

```
<? $lang['on'] = 'Включено';
$lang['off'] = 'Выключено';
...
?>
```

или лучше всего так

```
<? $on = 'Включено';
$off = 'Выключено';
...
?>
```

Или разницы не играет? Мне первый вариант более удобный, но может без открытия массива - это плохой вариант? П.С не ставьте минус, я учусь =)

Comment: А не повлияет ли на скорость или нагрузку сервера 
 если к примеру $block['user'] = 'тут будет содержатся блок с информацией размером 12 кб';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно, в чем проблема-то? Хотя вариант зависит от поставленной задачи. Если просто вывести значение, то возможны оба варианта. Если вы планируете использовать, к примеру, шаблонизатор, то лучше задавать переменные через массив.

Comment: Плюс что-то мне подсказывает, что массив `$lang` подразумевает многоязычность, в этом случае *не* использовать массив очень странно. Особенно порадует `global $lang_on, $lang_off, $leng_hello, [...15kb..], $lang_copyright;` =)

Answer (score 0):

Квадратные скобки уже подразумевают массив, потому в именах переменных их использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Что первый вариант, что второй, равнозначны. Если хотите использовать первый - используйте, никакая это не ошибка.

Comment: ага, только 1-й вариант будет ассоциативный массив с ключами "on" и "off", а второй вариант - две разных переменных

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать оба варианта.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант :

```
<?php
$v = 's';
$$v = 's var setted';
echo $s;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать оба. Но в больших проектах лучше массивы, xml или yaml